# How to present a SplitViewContoller from a TabBarContoller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a app having two tabs. Also using a splitviewcontroller. I want to link the tab bar (tab1) controller with the splitviewcontroller so that when tab1 is selected splitviewcontroller should be shown.

I tried attaching modal segue from tab to splitVC. But no luck. is there any way to do this using storyboard?

Please help.

Regards,
Lalit

Comment: I don' think is possible because as far as I know splitviewcontroller and tabbarcontroller must to be root view controller. So you have to write/find some custom code I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Both `UISplitViewController` and `UITabbarController` have arrays of viewControllers they display. So it's impossible to have them both on screen. But I think you can use `UISegmentedControl` instead of tabbar in one of yours views.